# Import excel to rails , and ignore the column headers from the file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on Rails project, where I am trying to import excel files, but I have the following issues:

I have my excel file with column headers like the following

|Name|Address|Total Balance|Balance

and in my model

Name, address, total, balance

I want to read every value form each column 
I have implement the following code:

```
def self.import(file)
        allowed_attributes = ["name","address"]
        spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
        header = spreadsheet.row(1)
        (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
            row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
            client = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
            client.attributes = row.to_hash.select { |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }
            client.save!
        end
    end


    def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
        case File.extname(file.original_filename)
            when '.csv' then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
            when '.xls' then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
            when '.xlsx' then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, file_warning: :ignore)
            else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
        end
    end
```

but my problem is that it doesn't read the column headers from excel
only if I make it the same as in allowd_attributes!

can I have other column names in excel file, and other in a model?
or ignore the column headers in the excel ? or somehow to convert the column headers , e.x "Address" -> "address" , "Total Balance" -> "total"
and so on..

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You really do need to clarify what you're asking here. But if I understand correctly, are you saying that in excel, the header names are, e.g. `"Address"` but you are comparing that with `"address"` in the Ruby code? If so, that comparison is going to fail. You'll have to make sure the column names match exactly. You don't have to change them in your Excel file. Let's say you have the Excel header name in a variable called `header1`. Then you could call `header1.downcase` and compare that with `"address"` or `header1.upcase` and compare that with `"ADDRESS"`.

Comment: However that strategy won't work if you are comparing column header names like `"Total balance"` and `"total"` since even after changing case they won't be equal.

Answer (score 2):

OK i did it with like this and it works great!
i am just specify every column!

```
def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
        name = spreadsheet.cell(i,'A')
        trading_name = spreadsheet.cell(i,'B')
        address = spreadsheet.cell(i,'D')

        @user = User.create(:name => name, :address =>address)

    end
end
```